# using mlockall to disable swapping?

Tags: elasticsearch

ES allows to disable swapping using mlockall setting for both Linux and windows, but in ES reference, it says:

**mlockall might cause the JVM or shell session to exit if it tries to allocate more memory than is available!**

My question is, is it best practice to set mlockall to true?

Answer (score 1):

**The best is to disable swapping**. Any system that is swapping will have its performance degraded no matter if we talk about Elasticsearch or other processes on that machine (needless to say the best is that ES is the single process running on the machine).

And your statement is wrong:

> ES allows to disable swapping using mlockall setting_

`mlockall` locks the memory allocated to Elasticsearch heap and not allowing the operating system to swap the heap memory to disk.

The [Elasticsearch documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/setup-configuration.html#setup-configuration-memory) offers three options, the first being the best, the last being used as a last resort:

> **Disable swap**
>
> The simplest option is to completely disable swap. Usually Elasticsearch is the only service running on a box, and its memory usage is controlled by the ES_HEAP_SIZE environment variable. There should be no need to have swap enabled.
>
> **Configure swappiness**
>
> The second option is to ensure that the sysctl value vm.swappiness is set to 0. This reduces the kernel’s tendency to swap and should not lead to swapping under normal circumstances, while still allowing the whole system to swap in emergency conditions.
>
> **mlockall**
>
> The third option is to use mlockall on Linux/Unix systems, or VirtualLock on Windows, to try to lock the process address space into RAM, preventing any Elasticsearch memory from being swapped out.

Comment: "ny system that is swapping will have its performance degraded no matter if we talk about Elasticsearch or other processes on that machine"

I recommend you read this: https://chrisdown.name/2018/01/02/in-defence-of-swap.html

Elastic.co's suggestions work fine on a system that is overdimentioned/just runs ES. If you're running multiple services on the same box, disabling swap can cause the OOM killer to give you a surprise